# Accessing Form1 Properties From Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, threadpool

I have an exceptionhandler function that basically just writes a line to a textbox on Form1. This works fine when being run normally but the second I use a thread to start a process it cannot access the property. No exception is thrown but no text is written to the textbox:

```
Public Sub ExceptionHandler(ByVal Description As String, Optional ByVal Message As String = Nothing)
    ' Add Error To Textbox
    If Message = Nothing Then
        Form1.txtErrLog.Text += Description & vbCrLf
        Log_Error(Description)
    Else
        Form1.txtErrLog.Text += Description & " - " & Message & vbCrLf
        Log_Error(Description, Message)
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("caught")
End Sub
```

Is it possible to access a form's properties from a thread this way or would it be easier to write to a text file or similar and refresh the textbox properties every 10 seconds or so (Don't see this as a good option but if  it's the only way it will have to do!).

Also, still new to VB so if I have done anything that isn't good practice please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't access any GUI component properties from the "wrong" thread (i.e. any thread other than the one running that component's event pump). You can use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)/[`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5kdt95.aspx) to execute a delegate on the right thread though.

There are lots of tutorials around this on the web - many will be written with examples in C#, but the underlying information is language-agnostic. See [Joe Albahari's threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use delegates. Search for delegates in VB.

Here a peace of code that does the job.

```
 Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal text As String)
```

Public Sub display_message(ByVal tx As String)

'prüfen ob invoke nötig ist
        If Me.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf display_message)
            Me.Invoke(d, tx)
        Else
            tx.Trim()
            Me.RichTextBox1.Text = tx
        End If

```
End Sub
```